# How could I display Hiragana Japanese character in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, uitableview, asianfonts

I am working on a Japanese iPhone app, I need to display in Japanese Hiragana in specific screen location, I tried to use NSSTING directly it doesn't work. Please what is the right way to do it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This is identical to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904050/display-hiragana-caracter-in-uitableview. - If you don't get answers, try to improve the question and provide more information, but don't repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

Use these methods, which defined in UITableVIewDataSouce protocl, to set custom NSString of the section header and index view:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Comment: I use those method, but for Hiragana Japanese caracter (あ, え, お..) it doesn't work, it require probably more addition...